# Javascript: Get ID of all Elements in a Section

Tags: javascript

I have a Script that maps all Elements starting with a specific ID:

```
var mirror = [...document.querySelectorAll('[id^="abc_"]')].map(elm => elm.id);
```

Now i need a function, that not all of the IDs are mapped, but just those in the section "foo"

```
<section id="foo">
  <div id="abc_1></div>
  <a id="abc_2"></a>
</section>

<section id="bar">
  <div id="abc_3></div>
  <a id="abc_4"></a>
</section>
```

With the obove function i get abc_1, abc_2, abc_3, abc_4. But i need only the IDs in section "foo" (abc_1 and abc_2)

Is there a way?

Comment: NOTE: you need to fix your HTML, there is a missing closing double quotes in the <div> tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var mirror = [...document.querySelectorAll('section#foo [id^="abc_"]')].map(elm => elm.id);

console.log(mirror)
```

```html
<section id="foo">
  <div id="abc_1">link1</div>
  <a id="abc_2">link2</a>
</section>

<section id="bar">
  <div id="abc_3">link3</div>
  <a id="abc_4">link4</a>
</section>
```

try this

```js
var mirror = [...document.querySelectorAll('section#foo [id^="abc_"]')].map(elm => elm.id);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily. Just pass the section  id `#foo` in the `.querySelectorAll()` like:

```
 document.querySelectorAll('#foo [id^="abc_"]')
```

This will find all the ids which start with `abc_` inside the `#foo` section only, instead of all sections.

```js
var mirror = [...document.querySelectorAll('#foo [id^="abc_"]')].map(elm => elm.id);
console.log( mirror )
```

```html
<section id="foo">
  <div id="abc_1"></div>
  <a id="abc_2"></a>
</section>

<section id="bar">
  <div id="abc_3"></div>
  <a id="abc_4"></a>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add another selector at the beginning section#foo

```js
let mirror = [...document.querySelectorAll('section#foo [id^="abc_"]')].map(ele => ele.id);
console.log(mirror);
```

```html
<section id="foo">
  <div id="abc_1"></div>
  <a id="abc_2"></a>
</section>

<section id="bar">
  <div id="abc_3"></div>
  <a id="abc_4"></a>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use as @Pain said but to be general without "section"

```
 var mirror = [...document.querySelectorAll('#foo [id^="abc_"]')].map(elm => elm.id);
```